# node / express js, get data after query

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js, express

I know it will be a trivial thing, but for this, I have not found much around, I'm using node/express js to query a database (MySQL), I'm using the following mode for queries:

*index.js*

```
exports.view= function(req, res){
var name = req.params.name;

req.getConnection(function(err,connection){
   
    var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM event WHERE linkname = ?',[name],function(err,rows)
    {
        if(err){
            console.log("Error Selecting : %s ",err );
            res.redirect('/');
        }else{
            console.log("rows: %s",rows);
            var body = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows));
            console.log("body: %s",body);
            res.render('form_payment',{page_title:"Showroom",data:rows});
        }  
       
     });

}); 
};
```

I would like to view the video, or in any case be able to use part of the query data, I read that you can use JSON.stringify(), JSON.parse() or both, but I always print the empty string on the screen, even when I try to print rows:

> rows:
>
> body:

The query works perfectly, in fact, I can pass the json of rows to the next activity with res.render (), but in this function (view) I just can not get and then use this data. My idea would be to be able to easily use the contents of rows, for example, something like rows[0].name, rows[0].id or rows.name, rows.code, ...

**[SOLVED]**

Remember to check if the variables that are passed to the query are correct, once this problem has been solved everything is back to work correctly and access to the rows elements, can occur with rows[0].id, rows[0].name, ...

I hope you can also help you find yourself in this situation.

Comment: console.log("body",body), also try SELECT * FROM event once so to confirm data is coming

Comment: Are you positive that `name` has a proper value? The console output suggests that the query runs successfully but returns an empty result.

Comment: Yeah, wrong input *name* for the query, now it works. but how can I pass data, without using a query, to this function? only from the page path? in reference to another question of mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49560187/get-data-from-ckeditor-4-to-another-ejs-file-in-express